# replace values in a column based on a condition in another column and retain remaining values in a dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, mapping, assign

I have a data frame, where i want to replace the values in column 'A' as NULL when values in column 'B' is either 'X' or 'Y'. For any other values in column 'B' (i.e., 'Z' or 'M') i want to retain the existing values in column 'A'

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| aaa | X |
| bbb | Y |
| ccc | X |
| ddd | Y |
| eee | Z |
| fff | M |

This is the expected result

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| NULL | X |
| NULL | Y |
| NULL | X |
| NULL | Y |
| eee | Z |
| fff | M |

This is what i have tried so far;

```
def func(colB):
    if colB in ['X' , 'Y']:
        return 'NULL'
df['A'] = df['B'].map(func)
```

This replaces the values in column A as NULL when B = ['x','y'] and returns blank when it is any other value. I want to retain the values if it does not match.

Comment: I suggest you to read upon [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html). You need `df.loc[df['B'].isin(['X', 'Y']), 'A'] = 'NULL'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using `where()` and `isin()`

```
df['A'] = df['A'].where(~df['B'].isin(['X','Y']),'NULL')
```

Output:

```
      A  B
0  NULL  X
1  NULL  Y
2  NULL  X
3  NULL  Y
4   eee  Z
5   fff  M
```

Comment: Hi @rhug123, I have a random question if you don't mind. What's the purpose of putting `~` before a column name ?

Comment: for a boolean dataframe or series, it flips the True and False values. So where isin would return True if it found an X or Y value, it would now return False after ~ is added.

Comment: Now I understand why. That's because isnotin() doesn't exist in pandas. Thank you so much !